# Password not recognized

Tags: password

I have installed Oracle VM 7 on Windows 11, than installed Ubuntu version below:
mma@mmaubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
mma@mmaubuntu:~$

When use sudo command this is what I get:
mma@mmaubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for mma:  
mma is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
mma@mmaubuntu:~$

My password is correct but it is not recognized. What is the problem? I I cannot use sudo I cannot do much on Ubuntu.

Comment: Try and run an actual command like. sudo apt-get update Enter the password you gave during install and see if it works.

Comment: I did that, I get "mma is not in the sudoers file response"

Comment: I reinstalled several times got same error...

Comment: Reinstalled what?

Comment: mma@mmaubuntu:~$ sudo apt -get update
[sudo] password for mma: 
mma is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: reinstalled Ubuntu

Comment: Try the command I gave you. You are adding extra stuff to it. This is the command again. sudo apt-get update  Do not add anything to the end of it.

Comment: No, I type your command, the rest is what ubuntu asks, that is my password, than when I enter the pw it responds with mma is not in sudoers file. they are all separate lines but in this platform they are printed as one line.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what has been messed up.

Comment: not only this but also the standard terminal is not booting up. I had to install Konsole. Otherwise I even do not have a terminal.

Comment: You never said this before. I wasted a lot of time trying to help without all the info. The install is corrupt. Start with downloading a new ISO. then run the verify and then the install. Here are the links to follow. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I had an earlier version of VM 6 and also an earlier version of Ubuntu. I uninstaled, deleted them and reinstalled everything. Could there be traces of old install on the machine.

Comment: my iso is the most recent. my VM 7 is most recent

Comment: Is the mma user in the sudo group (look in /etc/group)?  Only the first user at install time is normally added to this group, you need to add any others yourself.  Search this site for how do I add a user to the sudo group for details.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that, I hope it is not too complex.

Comment: Under etc even the group folder does not exist?

Comment: There is the /etc/sudoers.d folder which is empty...

Comment: The solution was reinstall Ubuntu in UNATTENDED box checked mode so that all answers can be inserted one by one. It worked...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Similar problem in 23.10. I can log in in terminal but not in the GUI. It does not recognize my password which is being entered correctly (no cap-lock, no keyboard stutter).